# Is there a way to search for downvoted or negative questions to answer?

Tags: support, feature-request

Questions with negative votes are generally not displayed at the top and are sometimes hidden.

Is there a way to specifically look up for negative voted or inactive questions on the site?

The questions with negative votes are generally not shown, but sometimes some of those questions might actually be good or may be informative if answered.

For example, if a question is downvoted for lack of clarity or due to not being focused, it may still have many good questions in it. Although an edit option and reopening features are available, it might fail to get the question back.

I know this site is for research-oriented questions, but some of the best teachers, etc. are on this site, and it might help some people to get a hold of things.

While most people would not like to answer bad questions, there should at least be a way to look them up. There might be a user who actually likes answering not so good questions.

To prevent bad questions from inhibiting answering good questions, maybe reduce the increase in reputation on answering a bad question to 25% of its actual value.

Also if someone has an acquaintance it will help them get an answer for their bad questions and that may help many others.

This feature may also help separate the good questions from the bad ones completely. While it isn't recommended for homework type questions or questions with more than -(7-10) votes, it may help the lesser negative questions.

After all, negative answers are still visible, aren't they?

What do you think?

Comment: You want the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, sometimes called SEDE, which lives at https://data.stackexchange.com. A full answer might include an appropriate query, but there are resources on other SE sites to learn that query language.